# How can I explain to lubridate which locale it should use?

Tags: r, date, parsing, time, lubridate

I can't get it to work, please can someone tell me what's wrong? On Windows with german locale.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
t0 <- "Dienstag, 19. Februar 2019 12:49:06"
t0 %>% parse_date_time(orders="ymd",locale="German_Germany.1252")
t0 %>% parse_date_time(orders="ymd",locale="de-DE.utf-8")
t0 %>% parse_date_time(orders="ymd")
```

None of these works... I thought parse_date_time is supposed to make things like that easier.
Or do I have to specify something like a format "%H %M %s" etc.?
Is there a package that just parses input like that without having to specify every detail?

Output of Sys.getlocale():

```
LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your locale is already German. Try using `as.POSIXct` with an appropriate `format`

```
as.POSIXct(t0, format = "%A, %d. %B %Y %T", tz = "UTC")
```

For example, this works on my English locale

```
t1 <- "Tuesday, 19. February 2019 12:49:06"
as.POSIXct(t1, format = "%A, %d. %B %Y %T", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2019-02-19 12:49:06 UTC"
```

and with `parse_date_time` this seems to work

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(t1, "dmYT")
#[1] "2019-02-19 12:49:06 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks, all of that works perfect. So the "orders" parameter of parse_date_time is the culprit in this case? I didn't realize that from the error message. Thanks :)